# Ionic 2 : No provider for Loading

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm new in Ionic 2 and need to use [Loading](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/loading/Loading/) ionic2 component
but when I added it to userPage constructor I get this error **No provider for Loading**

```
import { NavController, Loading } from 'ionic-angular';
export class UsersPage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private loading: Loading) {}
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be [**`LoadingController`**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#loading) instead of `Loading`:

```
import { NavController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
export class UsersPage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private loading: LoadingController) {}
}
```